# System command - doesn't get return

Tags: php, ffmpeg, system

Seem to have a problem with PHP system command - I place a command with it and if return code is above 0 - I cite failure otherwise I carry on.

It never seems to return on FFMPEG commands lower than a certain number of seconds (generally 3-5 seconds duration video encodes that are very quick to encode). Is this something that'd be from FFMPEG not returning properly or system command?

An example command:-

```
system('ffmpeg -i /home/test.wmv -f flv 340x160 -vcodec libx264 export.flv', $returnCode);
if($returnCode > 0) { error(); }
```

The only way to get round this seems to be to run a timer and check log files if nothing back after an amount of time but if anyone has any pointers - be gratefully received.

Comment: Have you tried `exec` (where you also get the output string)? Maybe that gives a hint..

Comment: This turned out to be a secondary, nested script that was being called and error'ing. Which hung the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you checked the code syntax? Seems you're closing the string earlier on the first parameter

Comment: This would be right - but that was my typing error on SO - not the problem. cheers tho